# Más de una llamada al endpoint en React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown, react-select

Estoy intentando realizar una llamada al endpoint para llenar un dropdown menu con react-select. Me funciona la primera llamada, pero no puedo hacer la segunda, o me da error de duplicidad de variables, o no se llena.

Creo un archivo con la lógica para hacer la llamada:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useFetch = ( url ) => {

    const [state, setState] = useState({
        data: null,
        isLoading: true,
        hasError: null,
    })

    const getFetch = async () => {

        setState({
            ...state,
            isLoading: true,
        });

        const resp = await fetch(url);
        const data = await resp.json();

        setState({
            data,
            isLoading: false,
            hasError: null,
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getFetch();
    }, [url])
   
    return {
        data:      state.data,
        isLoading: state.isLoading,
        hasError:  state.hasError,
    };
}
```

En el componente importo useFetch, y con el siguiente código hago la llamada:

```
const {data, isLoading} = useFetch('http://localhost:3000/api/countries');

const countries = data && data.map((country) => ({
    value: country.name,
    label: country.name
}));
```

Y al final lo llamo desde el formulario, en el Select necesario:

```
 <Select 
    name="country"
    options={countries}
    ...
/>
```

Todo esto funciona pero, por ejemplo, si quiero mostrar en otro select las ciudades, no he logrado hacerlo funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

como ya te respondiste tu pregunta, y viendo el resultado, yo te recomiendo que uses [Promise.All](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). aquí un ejemplo de como quedaría basándome en tu resultado.

```
const [countriesResponse, citiesResponse] = await Promise.all([
  useFetch('http://localhost:3000/api/countries'),
  useFetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cities')
]);

const countriesData = countriesResponse.data;
const countriesLoading = countriesResponse.isLoading;
const countries = countriesData && countriesData.map((country) => ({
  value: country.name,
  label: country.name
}));

const citiesData = citiesResponse.data;
const citiesLoading = citiesResponse.isLoading;
const cities = citiesData && citiesData.map((city) => ({
  value: city.name,
  label: city.name
}));
```

el codigo se puede mejorar, pero de esta manera sera mas entendible para ti, igual te recomiendo que uses un try catch para que puedas manejar excepciones y errores al llamar tu api, quedando de esta manera

```
try {
  const [countriesResponse, citiesResponse] = await Promise.all([
    useFetch('http://localhost:3000/api/countries'),
    useFetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cities')
  ]);

  //el resto del codigo


} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo resolví haciendo lo siguiente:

```
const {data: countriesData, isLoading: countriesLoading} = useFetch('http://localhost:3000/api/countries');
const countries = countriesData && countriesData.map((country) => ({
    value: country.name,
    label: country.name
}));

const {data: citiesData, isLoading: citiesLoading} = useFetch('http://localhost:3000/api/cities');
const cities = citiesData && citiesData.map((city) => ({
    value: city.name,
    label: city.name
}));
```

Lo había intentado poniendo el nombre a data (dataCountry) en vez de a countriesData. De esta manera me resultó.